# How to get simplexml child from multiple nodes in php

Tags: php, html, simplexml, nodes, children

I want to make a calender listing on varius deadlines on a HTML-page. I am using a XML-file as source that is not to much work to edit. The trouble is to get the right content presentet on the page.

This is somewhat how the xml will be:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<type>
<part1>
<month>
january
<date>
15.
<deadline>
deadline 1
deadline 2
deadline 3
</deadline>
</date>

<date>
24.
<deadline>
deadline 4
deadline 5
</deadline>
</date>

<date>
30.
<deadline>
deadline 6
deadline 7
</deadline>
</date>
</month>

<month>
february
<date>
6.
<deadline>
deadline 8
deadlline 9
</tekst>
</date>
</month>

</part1>
</type>
```

I need a php code to get each deadline on each date on each month on to the page.
I tried with "foreach" ant got the months, but got a problem when I have children on the nodes.

I would like the php til get somwhat like this output:

```
January
15. deadline 1
    deadline 2
    deadline 3

24. deadline 4
    deadline 5

30. deadline 6
    deadline 7

February
6. deadline 8
......
```

If anybody understand what I want, and can help me, that would be appreciated.

Comment: That is not valid XML. Have a look at http://www.w3schools.com/xml/  and http://www.xmlvalidation.com/

Comment: You should add the code you have so far to your question as well. So that the place where you have the problem becomes more clear.

Answer (score 1):

@starf is right, it is not correct XML. But that does not stop us from parsing it. For the top level we use XML parser, for lowest one - php function. This is working code

```
<?
$str = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<type>
<part1>
<month>
january
<date>
15.
<deadline>
deadline 1
deadline 2
deadline 3
</deadline>
</date>

<date>
24.
<deadline>
deadline 4
deadline 5
</deadline>
</date>

<date>
30.
<deadline>
deadline 6
deadline 7
</deadline>
</date>
</month>

<month>
february
<date>
6.
<deadline>
deadline 8
deadlline 9
</deadline>
</date>
</month>

</part1>
</type>';

$cal = new SimpleXMLElement($str);



$nmonth=0;
foreach($cal->part1->month as $month) {
    echo $month.'<br/>';
    $ndate = 0;
    foreach($cal->part1->month[$nmonth]->date as $date) {
        echo $date.'<br/>'; 
//          print_r($cal->part1->month[$nmonth++]->date[$ndate]->deadline);
        foreach($cal->part1->month[$nmonth]->date[$ndate]->deadline as $deadline) {
            $dead = preg_split('/\n/', $deadline);
                foreach ($dead as $d)
                if (!empty($d)) echo $d.'<br/>';
        }
    $ndate++;
    }
    $nmonth++;
}
```

result:

```
january 
15. 
deadline 1
deadline 2
deadline 3
24. 
deadline 4
deadline 5
30. 
deadline 6
deadline 7
february 
6. 
deadline 8
deadlline 9
```

Answer (score 0):

Quoting your question ...

> I am using a XML-file as source that is not to much work to edit

... I assume you are in control of the XML source file, so may I suggest you do some slight modifications to make it valid XML before trying to parse it? This is an example of how the modified XML might end up like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<type>
    <part1>
        <month name="January">
            <day number="15">
                <deadline>Deadline 1</deadline>
                <deadline>Deadline 2</deadline>
                <deadline>Deadline 3</deadline>
            </day>

            <day number="24">
                <deadline>Deadline 4</deadline>
                <deadline>Deadline 5</deadline>
            </day>

            <day number="30">
                <deadline>Deadline 6</deadline>
                <deadline>Deadline 7</deadline>
            </day>
        </month>

        <month name="February">
            <day number="6">
                <deadline>Deadline 8</deadline>
                <deadline>Deadline 9</deadline>
            </day>
        </month>
    </part1>
</type>
```

Example code for parsing this, generating the desired output:

```
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($source); // $source is XML content above

foreach ($xml->part1->month as $month) {
    echo $month['name'];

    foreach ($month->day as $day) {
        echo "<ol>";
        echo '<li value="', $day['number'] . '.' , '">';
        echo implode('<br />', (array)$day->deadline);
        echo '</li>';
        echo "</ol>";
    }
}
```

Output (indented for clarity):

```html
January
<ol>
  <li value="15.">
    Deadline 1<br/>
    Deadline 2<br/>
    Deadline 3
  </li>
</ol>
<ol>
  <li value="24.">
    Deadline 4<br/>
    Deadline 5
  </li>
</ol>
<ol>
  <li value="30.">
    Deadline 6<br/>
    Deadline 7
  </li>
</ol>

February
<ol>
  <li value="6.">
    Deadline 8<br/>
    Deadline 9
  </li>
</ol>
```